# Broadcast message once user enters or connects to Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, broadcast, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I need to broadcast a message to accept "terms and condition"  when devices try to connect to WiFi network. 
 Type of devices 
- Android device, IOS devices (iPhone,  Ipad),  Window devices ( Phone,  Laptop)

Comment: It sounds like you want a captive portal. A broadcast message is something else entirely. A broadcast is a message sent to every device on a network with a single message.

Comment: Thanks Ron Maupin , I am currently exploring the options. If the mentioned functionality could be possible with Broadcast message. Nothing like it as Captive portal would prove to an overhead.